# jQuery scroll skipping a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

when I click the first click me button it skips the second div and goes straight to the third div - does anyone know why this is? I think it could be due to the scrollTop function maybe? I want the first click me to take me to the second div and the second click me button to take me to the third div.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first">
            <h1>My Home Screen</h1>
            <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
            <script>
                $("button").click(function() {
                $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
                'slow');
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
            <script>
                $("button").click(function() {
                $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".third").offset().top},
                'slow');
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 h1 { 
    font-size: 12em;
    margin-top:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}

.first {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('home_screen.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.second {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('second_screen.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  }

.third {
width: auto;
height: 100vh;
background-image: url('third_screen.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code its overwriting itself.

You should make something like this:

```
<button data-go=".second">Go to 2</button>
<button data-go=".third">Go to 3</button>
```

And the Javascript should look like:

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var go_to = $(this).data('go');

   $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(go_to).offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

Where `data-go` = the selector of the div you want to scroll when the button is pressed

Check this working JSBIN http://jsbin.com/qohucowopu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You both script is working for both buttons as you directly used 'button' tag. To avoid this issue, assign an unique and different id for both buttons. And then use the ID to call the element in script. Here is the fixed code ---

```
   <div class="first">
        <h1>My Home Screen</h1>
        <button id='button1' type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <script>
            $("#button1").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
            'slow');
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <button  id='button2' type="button">Click Me!</button>
        <script>
            $("#button2").click(function() {
            $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".third").offset().top},
            'slow');
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    </div>
```